# Unable to call API from Metamask Snap

Tags: metamask, snap

I am currently working on a snap to integrate with XRPL. However, I have a problem when I want to get data from rippled server.

This is the URL that I am calling: `POST https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234`

This is my payload

```
{
    "method": "account_info",
    "params": [
        {
            "account": "rDtBYnfg4ehGdYKg98GbxPK63w2rWzYUpT",
            "ledger_index": "current",
        }
    ]
}
```

I always get error saying `Failed to fetch`
I am doing a call like this:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
});
```

And there are my initial permissions from snap manifest:

```
"initialPermissions": {
    "snap_confirm": {},
    "snap_manageState": {},
    "endowment:network-access": {}
},
```

I am always getting following error:

```
{
    "code": -32603,
    "message": "Failed to fetch",
    "data": {
        "originalError": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is invalid.

```
{
    "method": "account_info",
    "params": [
        {
            "account": "rDtBYnfg4ehGdYKg98GbxPK63w2rWzYUpT",
            "ledger_index": "current",
        }
    ]
}
```

should be changed to

```
{
    "method": "account_info",
    "params": [
        {
            "account": "rDtBYnfg4ehGdYKg98GbxPK63w2rWzYUpT",
            "ledger_index": "current"
        }
    ]
}
```

(mind the missing "," (comma) after `"ledger_index": "current"`

This should work then :)

Comment: Actually, the problem here was in CORS. Rippled does not have CORS support. https://github.com/XRPLF/rippled/issues/3513